# Main switch circuit with thyristor and bridge problem

Tags: switches, diodes, bridge-rectifier, motion, thyristor

Following circuit is a 220V touch switch from this website:

http://8085projects.info/m668-based-touch-sensitive-step-dimmer-circuit.html

I'm wondering how it works because the IC take its working voltage from + and - of diode bridge but when the thyristor switching the Load, voltage through the diode bridge become about 0.9V only and this voltage is lower than standard voltage to running the IC

[image]

There are also another circuit by same concept and this time from this website:

https://www.homemade-circuits.com/220v-touch-lamp-circuit-with-delay-timer/

[image]

So my question is:

1-Dose this method works?

2-If those circuits not correct so how motion switch with only **2 wires**  which available in the markets works?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to safely monitor the signal on the lamp you would find a classic phase-controlled AC waveform.

[image]

*Figure 1. Triac control of AC power.*

A dimmer will delay the power-on to achieve the required output power.

Any 2-wire electronic switch has two options for its self-power:

[image]

- If the turn-on of the thyristor (1) is delayed a few degrees after zero-cross then the voltage drop across the switch can be used to charge a capacitor - C1 (2). The chip is probably monitoring the zero-cross on pin 5 (3) and a time delay set by one of the other capacitors will initiate the thyristor trigger.
- Another method would be to switch the output off for a full cycle and use the voltage drop to charge the capacitor. This has the major disadvantage that the flicker would be noticable.